# how to get field score with sunspot

Tags: boost, sunspot

Can anyone help me to figure out how to get the specific field score ? I just know that the results.score is about the total score(relevancy) of search results, But How can I get specific field score  to make sure whether the result is searched out by that field by caculating the score.....any help would be appreciated, thanks!